# Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot' without conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I understand that a very similar question has been asked before, but the answer to said question was given in the context of anaconda, which did not help me as I am not familiar with anaconda. Anyhow:

I'm trying to get started with tensorflow in visual studio code, but when I try to type the following:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

I get this error: `Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot'` (along with pylint(import-error) in grayed-out text).

How do I resolve this error without using anaconda? If the answer relates to typing something into a terminal, *please* specify where the command is supposed to be typed in, as part of why I can't figure this out is because online solutions never specify where a command should go. Thanks!

Comment: You can open a terminal on the top menu of vscode,"terminal->new terminal".Or the shortcut is `ctrl+shift+\`` in windows.then type in "pip3 install matplotlib" in python3,"pip install matplotlib" in python2

Comment: I think you question now is not about the import matplotlib.pyplot,but how to install a python third part libary.You must learn some basic knowledge about python and pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend getting familiar with the basic concepts of Python first. From the different versions (Python 2.7, Python 3.x),  the structure (libraries), and good practices (use *virtual environments* to sandbox your structure).

- Why and how to create virtual environments, you may want to read [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/create-manage-python-virtual-environments/) or [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-development/).
- libraries are just as in any other language toolboxes with functions and data-structures. You need to install them on your system (Tensorflow is one example, matplotlib another). Most libraries can be installed via the package manager `pip` (which may install Python2.7 or Python3.x libraries, depending on what you default Python is or in what virtual environment you are currently working).
- be aware that different Python versions behave differently. Tensorflow is not available for all versions (not for Python2.7 in general but also not for all Python3.x versions).

Anyway, open up a command prompt (as you haven't specified your system, I assume windows. => open PowerShell or cmd).

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

This installs the library matplotlib in the root environment.
If you have an environment, activate it before issuing this command.

I strongly recommend reading an introduction to Python to get a better overview of the concept of Python.

Comment: Thank you! I tried doing this before, but for some reason it didn't work, perhaps because I used the wrong terminal. One more question: what's the difference between beginning the command with ```pip3``` versus just ```pip```?

Comment: `pip` is a broad wrapper linking to the current python binding. Independent if it is python-3.x or python-2.x. Calling `pip3` ensures that it is definitely python-3.x